# Android Camera2 Burst and ImageReader

Tags: android, computer-vision, android-camera, camera2

I am trying to get multiple pictures with different exposure time to perform my `HDR algorithm`. However, I cannot figure out how to use `captureBurst()` in Android `camera2 API` and `ImageReader` to save files.
My code will create duplicated files. Can anyone gives me a hand?

```
private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener =
            new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage()));
                }
            };

private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
        private final Image mImage;

        private ImageSaver(Image image) {
            mImage = image;

        }

        private File createNewImageFile() throws IOException {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
            File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera");
            File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
            byteBuffer.get(bytes);

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

            try {
                File newFile = null;
                try {
                    newFile = createNewImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                fileOutputStream.write(bytes);

                mImageFileNameList.add(newFile.getName());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void captureStillImage() {
        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder captureStillBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureStillBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            CaptureRequest.Builder captureStillBuilder2 = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureStillBuilder2.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,
                    ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,
                    ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback =
                    new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                            unlockFocus();
                        }
                    };

            List<CaptureRequest> list = new ArrayList<>();

            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, ONE_SECOND / 100);

            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, ONE_SECOND / 20);

            list.add(captureStillBuilder.build());
            list.add(captureStillBuilder2.build());

            mCameraCaptureSession.captureBurst(list, captureCallback, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION instead of CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look of that.

Comment: Hi, @MaximMetelskiy can you share the sample burst image capture mode, I want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If everything seems to work otherwise, and your issue is just the file names getting duplicated, that may just be because your phone can capture two JPEGs faster than 1 second apart.

Your format string for the image file name is: "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
This doesn't include any fractional seconds, so pictures taken at, say
12:35:15.100 and 12:35:15.700 (600 ms apart) will map to the same filename,
IMG_..._123515.jpg.

You can just add "_SSS" to your string to include milliseconds as well, per the [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation, which should disambiguate your filenames unless they're being captured *really* fast.

Alternatively, you could keep some sort of counter for files with the same name, and append _1, _2, etc when there's a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code from a similar scenario, where I am saving my files in a folder named C2 under the external Pictures folder:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    String currentDateTime = generateTimestamp();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()
            + "/C2/" + mCount++ + "_" + currentDateTime + ".jpg");
    if (mCount == 3)  mCount = 1; // Reset the counter
    mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), file));
}
```

and mCount is set as

```
private int mCount = 1;
```

And generateTimestamp is from Google's sample code:

```
/**
 * Generate a string containing a formatted timestamp with the current date and time.
 *
 * @return a {@link String} representing a time.
 */
private static String generateTimestamp() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS", Locale.US);
    return sdf.format(new Date());
}
```